# Silverlight 4 Audio Compression

Tags: silverlight, encoding, audio, mp3

Any suggestions on how to implement Compression of captured Audio in a Silverlight 4 Application? I'd prefer something lossy like MP3 or AAC but after my intial research only turned out one lonely pure C# FLAC encoder/decoder, anything better than this would be nice.

Please note that **sending uncompressed audio to the server and compress it there is not an option** because of a) traffic cost and b) the audio is additionally encrypted by the client so the server never sees the source material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any implementations of proprietary compression algorithms in C#. You pretty much would have to implement your own. ADPCM is silmple and offers 4:1 compression ratio. More on the subject: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/145729/374278.aspx

Comment: Yes I know. The Problem with ADPCM is that its only 4 Bit per Sample.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer because it got me thinking again about Speech Codecs and I discovered this: http://cspeex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be C#?  LAME is a pretty good, very configurable MP3 encoding library.

http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Using Lame invokes PInvoke which in turn requires elevated permission and OOB execution of silverlight applications so that not an option.

Comment: you can also use a process without involving a PInvoke.